# Русский текст из getwindowtext

Tags: c++, winapi, кодировка

В Qt 4.8 вызываю функцию getwindowtext, которая во второй параметр выдает заголовок окна. Все бы ничего, работает, но вместо кириллицы пишет кракозябры. Все перепробовал.

Comment: Добавте в вопрос ваш код.

Comment: Используйте юникодную версию функции, т.е. GetWindowTextW, либо настройте проект на использование юникода.